# How to properly set up NSPopover with separate viewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nspopover

I have created an extremely simple test program. It has one button. Clicking the button brings up an `NSPopover` with a label. That label is on a separate xib file with its own `NSViewController`.

The Goal is to, when on the main screen, when I click the button, a popover will show the xib file of the `viewcontroller`. And the label of the xib file should have it's text set to "It works".

Well.. It works, but only on **after** the second loading of the popover. On the first click of the button, the label still has its old default value. But from the 2nd click and onwards, "It works".  **Does any one have an idea what can be causing this issue? Its only about 5 lines of code** The code can be seen on this repository --> https://github.com/patchthecode/testtest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `[mainScreenPopoverViewController view];` in `- (void)windowDidLoad` method. This will load your view into memory.

Before call `[mainScreenPopoverViewController view];`  (textfield address is 0x0)

[image]

You should not use strong property for all IBOutlet.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
```

Take a look at [Resource Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6)

> From a practical perspective, in iOS and OS X outlets should be
>   defined as declared properties. Outlets should generally be weak,
>   except for those from File’s Owner to top-level objects in a nib file
>   (or, in iOS, a storyboard scene) which should be strong. Outlets that
>   you create should therefore typically be weak, because:
>
> - Outlets that you create to subviews of a view controller’s view or a
>     window controller’s window, for example, are arbitrary references
>     between objects that do not imply ownership.
> - The strong outlets are    frequently specified by framework classes (for example,
>     UIViewController’s view outlet, or NSWindowController’s window
>     outlet).

Comment: Hi, ok i know about the strong/weak IBoutlets. My error. I just did this test app so show the pop over code. One thing, solution works, but is there some link with an explanation for why this is? I had the belief that the nib loading code already instantiates the objects into memory..

Comment: Use breakpoint un IBAction and check the address of textfield.

Comment: As i set the break point, i understand whats going on now. thanks.